# How to make objects in Google cloud storage open instead of download?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want users to be able to open the files stored in GCP's Storage without the need to download them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the metadata of your file,

- Either in the GUI by clicking on the 3 dots at the end of the file's line and then on *Edit metadata*
- Or by adding them with the [`gsutil` command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/setmeta)

You have to change the `content-type` of your file. If this content type is known by your browser (or one of its extensions), the file is directly displayed into the browser. Else, it is downloaded.

The [content type is set by default](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#content-type) when you upload the file.