# The browser opens a json file instead of downloading it from google storage

Tags: json, laravel, google-cloud-storage

tI am using laravel 6.2 version and trying to upload a .json file to google storage bucket, but when I try to download the file the browser opens it instead of downloading it, so I am trying to force download it by setting 'ContentDisposition => attachment;'

```
$options = array('ContentType' => 'application/json', 'ContentDisposition' => 'attachment', 'Metadata' => ['ContentType'=> 'application/json','ContentDisposition' => 'attachment']);
Storage::disk('storage_bucket')->put('file_path', 'file_content', $options);
```

I also tried

```
Storage::disk('storage_bucket')->getDriver()->put('file_path', 'file_content', $options);
```

on the fron-end I am using v-btn

```
       <v-btn
          icon
          :href="item.download"
          v-on="on"
          download
        >
          <v-icon small> fa-download </v-icon>
        </v-btn>
```

but didn't work also

Comment: you may check the suggestions in this [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893153/google-cloud-storage-force-download) & [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60601863/how-to-make-objects-in-google-cloud-storage-open-instead-of-download)